# Best tutorial to learn SSIS

Tags: ssis

Which book is best to learn SSIS. Actually in my project we need to take onput from CVS file and after processing the data in SQL server 2008  we have export it back to excel file. ASP.NET is used as UI for this.
Thanks,
Nabin

Answer (score 4):

I completely agree with Cade in terms of simply working with it. I found that trying to follow specific "tutorials" to try and learn the package didn't really help but having a number of useful resources definitely came in handy.

At work, we had [this book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Pro-Server-2005-Integration-Services/dp/1590598970/ref=sr_1_12?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1276208267&sr=1-12) kicking around but really it just went over the flow objects available without going into any real-world examples. Jamie Thomson's blogs ([here](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/) and [here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/)) are both excellent online resources though and have been really helpful for me personally.

Comment: any updates in 2017 ? Jamie Thomsons or new gurus about ***SSIS*** ? For eg. http://www.jasonstrate.com/2011/01/31-days-of-ssis-the-introduction/ but 2011 year

Answer (score 3):

Try this book:

[http://www.amazon.com/Professional-Microsoft-Integration-Services-Programmer/dp/0470247959](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470247959)

The best way to learn SSIS is just to do it.  Probably best to start and then refer to the book.  Because the tool is so GUI intensive, I tended to get more after reading the book later once I was already familiar with the environment somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the material some times couldn't solve your real time migration by missing some perticular functionality related to your project. I worked on your scenario case of migrating database to SQL using intermediate CSV or text files.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537533(SQL.100).aspx

we migrated nearly 1TB in 30 min using SSIS 2008.

this could help to get the information on specific properties of souce file according to our requirements.

thanks
prav